# Step count method example for recursion

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I need to find step count of recursive algorithm for Fibonacci series. 
Can anyone explain how to find step count for any recursive algorithms?

```
fibo(n)
{
  if(n=2)
    return 1
  else
    return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
}
```

Comment: What is a step count?

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variable like this :

```
int stepCount=0;
fibo(n) {
   stepCount+=1;
   if(n=2) return 1;
   else return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

step is 1 for simple computation  and 0  when no computation is required

```
                                              step
    1 fibo(n)                                   0
    2 {                                         0
    3  if(n=2)                                  1
    4    return 1                               1
    5  else                                     0
    6    return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)             1+T(n-1)+T(n-2)
    7  }                                        0
```

If n=2 then  1,2,3,4 lines will be execute only 1 time
So for n=2

```
t(n)=  1*0 + 1*0 + 1*1 + 1*1
```

if n>2
line 1,2,3,5,6,7 will be executed out of which 3 and 6 have step>0 so line 3 and 6 will contribute for time(else part take 0 step . If part have computation and  condition of if block will determine whether to execute if part or else part. Thats why we take compuation of else 0)

```
so for n>2 
T(n)=1+1+T(n-1)+T(n-2)

T(n)={
        2 for n=2
        2+T(n-1)+T(n-2)  for n>2
      }
```